# Entropy: whats the difference between bits and bytes?

Tags: encryption, openssl, byte

If I use `openssl` to generate some random data (for a keyfile, for example):

```
openssl rand -hex 2048 >/tmp/file
```

Is this 4097 bits (or bytes?) of entropy?

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 4097 Oct 30 20:01 /tmp/file
```

Comment: It's 2048 bytes, hex-encoded (ie a byte = 69 in decimal will be printed as '45') and followed by a newline (2048 * 2 + 1). If you want to raw bytes, don't use the `-hex` option ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this 4097 bits (or bytes?) of entropy?

Neither. Entropy is a property of *how* the random data was generated (see, e.g., this [Crypto.SE post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51302/)), not *how much* of it was generated. If `openssl rand` could generate data with x bits of entropy, that would still be x bits of entropy irrespective of whether you told it to output 1 bit or 1 TB.

A detailed discussion of entropy would likely be off-topic here. Maybe ask on [Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).